# String split by certain condition

Tags: ruby, string, split

I'd like to split this string by `' '` only if it has `':'`:

```
"A:Hey B:Are C:You there"
```

`C:You there` should be not split. The result should be:

```
["A:Hey", "B:Are", "C:You there"]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\s+(?=\S*:)
```

You can split by this.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hF7zZ1/4

This basically use a `lookahead` to make sure that the `space` which is being split upon is followed by `non space characters and :` .So it will work as you want.

Comment: Could you explain what each means? I'm very newbie to dev. Thanks!

Comment: Plus, i tried like this `string.split('\s+(?=\S*:)')` but doesnt work.

Comment: @ZHH `string.split(/\s+(?=\S*:)/)`

Comment: Why is it `*` after `\S`? The result may be the same, but from the meaning, I think it should be rather `+`, or even without a quantifier.

Comment: @sawa if the string is `A:Hey :Hey` i guess it should be split too

Comment: @vks My interpretation was that a colon will always be preceded by some letter (most likely a single letter).